# Laravel Order by pivot table

Tags: laravel

I have 3 tables:

- opportunities: id, name
- customers: id, name
- customer_opportunity: customer_id, opportunity_id, won (=1/0)

I want to list all opportunities with the their customers and order the costumers by "won". 
Hence the customer(s) whom has won the opportunity will be shown first.

```
        $opportunities = \App\Opportunity:: where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
                                        ->with('customers')
                                        ->orderByDesc('customer_opportunity.won')
                                        ->get();
```

I cannot order by customer_opportunity since it does not find the table.

Is there a way to sort the return objects, from the pivot->won?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Laravel's `join()` method:

```
$opportunities = \App\Opportunity::where('company_id', Auth::user()->company_id)
                ->with('customers')
                ->join('customer_opportunity', 'customer_id', '=', 'customers.id')
                ->join('opportunities', 'opportunities.id', '=', 'customer_opportunity.opportunity_id')
                ->orderBy('customer_opportunity.won', 'desc')
                ->get();
```